# jQuery - Highlight divs that contain classes when button clicked

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a jquery snippet that highlights divs by class depending on the button that is clicked.  With some help from a stack user I am at this point...

```
<ul class="mybuttons">
    <li><a href="#" data-col="red" class="link red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="green" class="link green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="yellow" class="link yellow">Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="blue" class="link blue">Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-col="orange" class="link orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="test red blue">Red - Blue</div>
<div class="test blue">Blue</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test blue yellow">Blue - Yellow</div>
<div class="test orange">Orange</div>
<div class="test red">Red</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test green blue">Green - Blue</div>
<div class="test orange">Orange</div>
<div class="test yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="test green">Green</div>
<div class="test blue">Blue</div>
```

-

```
.test{height:30px;width:250px;background:lightgrey;margin-bottom:10px;border:black 1px solid;text-align:center}

.link{opacity:.5;}
.main{background:blue;color:white;}
.active{opacity:1;}

.link.red{background:red;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.green{background:green;green:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.yellow{background:yellow;color:black;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.blue{background:blue;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
.link.orange{background:orange;color:white;width:50px;height:30px;text-decoration:none;}
```

-

```
$links = $('.link');
$links.click(function(e) {
    //Get our variables, simply $(this) and the colour
    var $this = $(this),
        color = $this.data('col');

    //Toggle the active class on this link
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    //Remove .main on all .test's
    $(".test").removeClass("main");

    //Map the active link's data-col with a dot attributes to an array
    //Join it up to make a selector
    var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
        return "."+$(this).data('col');
    }).get().join();

    //Add the class back on to matches
    $(selector).addClass('main');

    //Finally, prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

-

http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/q0f7w8zj/3/

The next stage I am trying to achieve is if more than one link is selected then only highlight divs that contain both those links.

For example if the Blue and the Yellow links are selected then the only div that should be highlighted is...

```
<div class="test blue yellow">Blue - Yellow</div>
```

Anyone have an example or can point me in the direction of some reading to try and achieve this?

Comment: yeah this is working as expected .. what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, all you need to do is update one line:

change `}).get().join();`

To `}).get().join('');`

Providing no separtor to [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) results in a string delimited with commas which acts as a union selector. Omitting the commas leads to an intersect so that elements must have all of the classes.

Comment: This solution is better than mine as it doesn't need any additional function

Comment: Agreed, your solution worked fine for me but this one is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "," that is included in the selector, and it will work as expected:

```
var selector = $links.filter('.active').map(function(){
    return "."+$(this).data('col');
}).get().join().replace(/,/g,"");
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/q0f7w8zj/4/